# how to delete a data looks like an other data in R

Tags: r, dplyr

i want to delete a data with a minim time, but in the name is like each other

```
df1 <- data.frame(
  name = c(
    "A. MAHJUM-61365",
    "A. MAHJUM-61365. MAHJUM-61365",
    "A. RIZAL. AD-11002795",
    "A. RIZAL. AD-11002795. RIZAL. AD-11002795",
    "ABD. KADIR-60447",
    "ABD. KADIR-60447ABD. KADIR-60447",
    "ABD. KAHAR-62551",
    "ABD. RASYID DS-11002082",
    "ABDREAS APUNG @SANY",
    "ABDUL AZIS @HYUNDAI",
    "ABDUL AZIZ @HYUNDAY",
    "ABDUL AZIZ@HYUNDAI"
  ),

time=c(100,5,40,6,55,7,90,29,100,20,100,6))
```

and the df would be like this

```
df2=data.frame(name=c(
"A. MAHJUM-61365"
"A. RIZAL. AD-11002795"
"ABD. KADIR-60447"
"ABD. KAHAR-62551"
"ABD. RASYID DS-11002082"
"ABDREAS APUNG @SANY"
"ABDUL AZIS @HYUNDAY"),
time=c(100,40,55,90,29,100,100))
```

my expected the df like to df2

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You can try `adist` and use `hclust` to find similar names. Use `ave` to find the maximum.

```
x <- adist(df1$name, partial=TRUE)
i <- cutree(hclust(as.dist(pmin(x, t(x)))), h=2)

df1[df1$time == ave(df1$time, i, FUN=max),]
#                      name time
#1          A. MAHJUM-61365  100
#3    A. RIZAL. AD-11002795   40
#5         ABD. KADIR-60447   55
#7         ABD. KAHAR-62551   90
#8  ABD. RASYID DS-11002082   29
#9      ABDREAS APUNG @SANY  100
#11     ABDUL AZIZ @HYUNDAY  100
```